# Paths confusion: relative / absolute / relative to DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Tags: php, include-path

I have just started learning PHP and I have read several answers to pretty much similar question, but it didn't help.

I have several files:

```
index.php 
folder1\file.php
folder2\file.php
```

So `index.php` includes `folder1\file.php` and it is really easy. Then `folder1\file.php` includes `folder2\file.php`. The book I am reading says to do this I have to write this inside `folder1\file.php`:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . 'folder2/file.php';
```

So basically why didn't they do this?

```
require 'folder2/file.php';
```

As far as I understood, all the paths are always relative to the initial script's location and it works just fine on my machine.

I still don't get why not use  `.\folder\file.php` which would keep it working if I move my directory deeper or copy the whole website to another machine.

According to the manual: If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or `\` on Windows, or `/` on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with `.` or `..`) — the include path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with `../`, the parser will look in the parent directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP manual [says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Files are included based on the file
>   path given or, if none is given, the
>   [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) specified. If the file
>   isn't found in the include_path,
>   include() will finally check in the
>   calling script's own directory and the
>   current working directory before
>   failing.

So it's always a best practice to set the include path in your master file (in your case, index.php) using the **set_include_path()** method.

When working with frameworks or customised servers, it is good to specify your include path without leaving behind the system defined include paths by doing the following:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

That way, your new include path will be added to the existing paths.

For what you have asked in the question, it is always better to specify the include path as I mentioned above and then refer your files relatively. If in case in future you want to move your files, editing just one line will do instead of finding and replacing in hundreds of files.

### Example:

**index.php:**

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
require('folder1/file.php');
```

**folder1/file.php:**

```
require('folder2/file.php');
```

**folder2/file.php:**

```
require('folder3/file.php');
```

and so on..

Comment: The path that gets set after the call of set_include_path is the following: SCRIPTBASEphp_classes;.;/usr/local/php5/PEAR;Z:/home/localhost/www. If a script is one folder deeper than the root it won't work! I still don't get why not use ".\folder\file.php". According to the manual: If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the parser will look in the parent directory.

Comment: Starting with a root slash works differently in different operating environments. IIS will start looking at the root of the virtual host (like `C:\inetpub\sites\yoursite`), while any Unix based system is going to start looking at the root of the hard drive. A guaranteed pain if you are migrating in future.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because it good practice. Not all you scripts using folder2/file.php are going to be called from the root directory.

Say if you have

```
index.php
folder1\file.php
folder2\file.php
folder3\use-folder2.php
```

and you try to include file.php from folder2 from use-folder2.php then using your idea the path it will look for the file would be :

```
folder3\folder2\file.php
```

which doesn't exists.

That's why they are making you start your path from the root of your web site.

Comment: thanks, that was fast. But what if I for some reason have to move all my scripts one folder deeper - newfolder\index.php etc. I will have to change all of the paths in requires!

Comment: That's why as a good practice, you have an include directory at the root of your website where you add all the file that are included in other files. Using the $_SERVER[DocumentRoot] in your inclusion will make all the rest of your code insensitive to how deep you put these new files.